# List characters in a string

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public void Calculate(){

   String name1="tsebo";
   String name2="mokoena";

   String sentance= name1.toLowerCase().trim()+" true love "+
            name2.toLowerCase().trim();
    String word=sentance.replaceAll(" ","").trim();
    List<String> original=Arrays.stream(word.split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.print(original);
}
```

The output I get:

`[, t, s, e, b, o, t, r, u, e, l, o, v, e, m, o, k, o, e, n, a]`

The problem is the first empty char before "t". Help remove it.

Comment: `.split("")` is not recommended. Do you want an array of characters? then use `word.toCharArray()`. Or `word.chars()` if you want a `Stream` to continue working with it.

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: It works for me.  What is your question?

Comment: @Clashsoft `.chars()` and `.toCharArray()` are not recommended. They split surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot reproduce. Your code when copy-pasted works as you intended; no empty first element.

---

When working character-by-character, better to use Unicode [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). Each of the 143,859 characters defined in Unicode is assigned a number, called a code point, from zero to just over a million.

Get a [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) of these integer code point numbers, in the form of a sequence of `int` primitive values.

```java
IntStream codePointStream = "love".codePoints();
```

Capture those numbers to a list. Convert from primitive `int` to object `Integer`.

```java
List < Integer > codePoints = codePointStream.boxed().toList();
```

> codePoints.toString(): [108, 111, 118, 101, 128152]

Map those to a list of single-character `String` objects, to get back to the characters. Call [`Character.toString( codePoint )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) to generate the text.

```
List < String > characters = codePoints.stream().map( Character :: toString ).toList();
```

> characters = [l, o, v, e, ]

We could combine those.

```java
List < String > characters =
        "love"
                .codePoints()
                .mapToObj( Character :: toString )
                .toList();
```

> characters = [l, o, v, e, ]

Before Java 16, replace `.toList()` with the more verbose `.collect( Collectors.toList() )`.

Comment: this's an excelent answer, but the question is asking for: `.collect( Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]");`

Comment: @bichoFlyer Ahh, no it’s not. I have no idea what you are referring to. The Question is about generating a string representing a list of strings. No “joining”.